# problem setting int value, unrecognized selector sent to instance.... iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem

in my application i'm trying to send an int value from one view to another view. To do this i'm setting up a navbar button programmatically and passing it an action from the same class that's creating the button. In the next view that will load i have a property that i'll set when the user clicks the navbar button. The problem is that the application crashes when i set this value. I have the int value in a @property in the view's h class and then i have the @synthesize below the @implementation line.

**Here is the code for the navbar button, this is done in the `initWithNibName` method:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *contentsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contents"                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showBookContents)];


        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:contentsButton];
        [contentsButton release];
```

**Here is the method that i pass to the button when it's created:**

```
-(IBAction)showBookContents{
    BookContentsViewController *contentsViewController = [[BookContentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookContentsViewController" bundle:nil];

    contentsViewController.selectedBookId = self.selectedBook._id;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:contentsViewController animated:YES];

    [contentsViewController release];

}
```

**Here is the class that will be loaded when the use clicks the navbar button:**

```
@interface BookContentsViewController : UIViewController {
    int selectedBookId;
}

@property int selectedBookId;

@end
```

**Here is the implementation for the above class:**

```
@implementation BookContentsViewController

@synthesize selectedBookId;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

As you can see the `@property` and `@synthesize` looks fine. Here is the error i get:

**2011-06-13 11:48:42.321 BookApp[22762:207] -[BookDescriptionViewController setSelectedBookId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d9f070
2011-06-13 11:48:42.323 BookApp[22762:207] ** ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BookDescriptionViewController setSelectedBookId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d9f070'**

What can the problem be guys?

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

make this selectedBookId NSString and then try.

```
NSString *selectedBookId;
int selectedBookIdIntegerValue;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString selectedBookId;
```

Change in this method

```
-(IBAction)showBookContents{
    BookContentsViewController *contentsViewController = [[BookContentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookContentsViewController" bundle:nil];

    contentsViewController.selectedBookId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.selectedBook._id];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:contentsViewController animated:YES];

    [contentsViewController release];

}
```

dont forget to release selectedBookId  in dealloc of BookContentsViewController.

since selectedBookId is now NSString
You might need integer value so what you do is
 `selectedBookIdIntegerValue=[self.selectedBookId intValue];`

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work. But i found something, the BookContentsViewController is not being called. I put an NSLog in the viewDidLoad and didn't see this log. As @Simon Lee said it seems that the File's Owner for the view is messed up but i don't know how to change it to BookContentsViewController.

Comment: it's working. I had a lot of breakpoints activated, that's why the application stopped. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method on an instance of `BookDescriptionViewController` however it is defined in `BookContentsViewController`

Comment: Yeah but BookContentsViewController is instantiated inside the instance of BookDescriptionViewController. I don't see why it's not working. I did the same thing in another class and it worked. Do you have a possible solution? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check the nib file has the correct class for files owner.... the issue is that despite you calling setSelectedBookId on something you *think* is a BookContentsViewController, it is actually a BookDescriptionViewController....

Comment: Put a breakpoint on.... contentsViewController.selectedBookId = self.selectedBook._id; and check what class the contentsViewController is...

Comment: where can i see what class the contentsViewController is? in the debugger area? as i said before, the view is working if i don't try to set that int value.

Comment: i checked the nib file and it's File's Owner is set to BookContentsViewController. I checked it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value by using NSInteger as:

```
@interface BookContentsViewController : UIViewController {
    NSInteger CurrentBookId;
}
@property(assign) NSInteger CurrentBookId;
@end


@implementation BookContentsViewController
@synthesize CurrentBookId;
```

Here is you bar button Action:

```
-(IBAction)showBookContents{
BookContentsViewController *contentsViewController = [[BookContentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookContentsViewController" bundle:nil];

contentsViewController.CurrentBookId = self.bookId;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:contentsViewController animated:YES];

[contentsViewController release];

}
```